# SqlDataAdapter Fill method returns 0

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have a fill method that has worked for months and suddenly stopped working.

SP executes fine interactively, connection is open in debug, etc.

I can use a datareader and it will work just fine. I have to think it's related to SqlClient somehow, right? Any ideas?

Thanks

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
DataSet TestDataSet = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;

command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = sqlSP;
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

try
{
    connection.Open();

    dataAdapter= new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    dataAdapter.Fill(TestDataSet );
    return (TestDataSet );
}

catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: Do you really have that empty catch block? If yes it is useless and harmful. In this way you never see if something is wrong in your code.

Comment: No - I just removed that code from here for simpler reading.

Comment: The code seems to be correct. Could it be something with the connection? (wrong database?)

Comment: Nope - dbReader works fine with the same connection and command. It's baffling

Comment: The code is correct. I think you should use sqlprofiler, whether the query is executing at the database end or not. This can lead towards the solution where is the actual problem.if you haven't any idea regarding sqlprofiler then this link will be helpful [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21371/SQL-Server-Profiler-Step-by-Step)

Comment: Yes, like I say, there's no problem executing the sp. I can add an executescalar and dbreader right along side (using same command and connection) and all three execute on the db. It almost has to have something to do with the adapter itself. I was hoping someone had run into this before.